# How do I tweet from my bot account when the bot app is created under a separate account?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-oauth, tweets

I'm quite a novice, so please excuse my ignorance.

I've created a developer account on my personal Twitter account and my end goal is to have another account occasionally tweet something. I'm using tweepy and have successfully managed to tweet something, albeit from my account.

Twitter developer accounts can get their API key and secret, as well as an Access key and secret. What I'm trying to figure out is how to get my bot account's keys to have *it* tweet instead of my account.
After reading countless pages online as well as the docs, there seems to be a way to get auth another user through three-legged auth and [pin-based auth](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/pin-based-oauth), which seems like the correct route to my goal.

However, I have no idea where to go from here. The three-legged auth page asks for various required fields, of which I have no idea what to fill with (Callback URLs and Website URL). Moreover, the docs describe the process as one that needs to be initiated by the dev account, and I have no idea how to initiate that process at all.

Any help or guidance on what to do? My tweepy script is fully finished and just needs to be hooked up to the Twitter API.

Thanks.

**EDIT & SOLUTION (03/18/2021):**
Thanks to the comment by Sim leading to the article, I was able to derive a python script using Tweepy to authorize the bot using pin-based auth, [found here](https://gist.github.com/CombustibleToast/0e175a174d3666fff0c498097f021e01#file-pinbasedbotauth-py). I'd give the article a read regardless, but once it starts telling you to create .js and .json files, stop there and use my script. That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that worked for me, I think this is what you need.  https://dev.to/stratospher/many-bot-accounts-using-1-twitter-developer-account-17ff